# Can't start a different app from my app using package name

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am trying to open Chrome app from my application. Code is simple.

I got the package name of Chrome app by using this code:

```
    PackageManager manager = Values.activity.getPackageManager();

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities){
            apps.add(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
        }

        //the package name of Chrome from packagemanager is "com.android.chrome"
```

And I tried to open Chrome like this:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

But nothing happens without an error and my logcat says this:

```
12-28 20:28:52.298: I/ActivityManager(482): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.chrome cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main} from pid 20474
```

What am I missing? Is the package name retrieved from packagemanager wrong?

Comment: There are some security restriction applied by Android system to start other application. First is if second application had defined some action <intent-filter> to start those component. Secondly there could be permission defined with android:protectionLevel="signature". you can use getActivityInfo(ComponentName component, int flags) to retrieve all of the information we know about a particular activity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is generic code to launch browser from your application:

```
                String uriString = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(uriString));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }   else {
                    // Any browser is not available
                }
```

May I know why you want to launch Chrome only?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But opening Chrome app is just an example. I want to create many buttons that open other apps too.

Comment: Then your question is wrong. You should clearly mention what you are doing and what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry for not clearing enough for my goals. I was trying to open another application in my launcher app. But in the main activity in my launcher app which is with default and home filters in manifest cannot open other applications. I don't know why. I just did a workaround.